# Geo Node: Instance on Points and Rotation problem - I want to create something like the "yellow" for different shapes like pentagons and hexagons etc

Tags: geometry-nodes

The idea is to have different shapes like pentagons or octagons but I want to rotate the edges seperated diagonal so it will look like the yellow drawing.

I tried to "instance on points" with the green points edges as "instance" and the red points as "points" but as you can see it has an offset and I am not sure if the rotation is exact.

If you have an idea how to fix this please let me know. Or if you know a better way to get what I want let me know your idea so I can test it out. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clear what you mean, so I'll guess: you want to start with a regular polygon, rotate the edges of that polygon, but keep the edges connected. You could do it this way:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, It is not exactly what I want but I will make a new post with better explaining.